# Integrating CKEditor in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ckeditor

Is it possible to integrate CKEditor to SharePoint2010's EDIT ITEM or ADD ITEM page without using `CKEditor for SharePoint`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the default editor with CKEditor, it is going to be hard. Remember that the default editor is integrated in the ribbon. If you want to use it for some reason in a webpart or on specific situations like in a page layout you can follow something along the lines of this:

http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/features/article.php/3928401/Sharepoint-Tools-You-Can-Use-CKEditor.htm

Comment: Eh, I have done it by javascript,but now the biggest problem is the integration of ckfinder.